# Why is cos(t+Y) stationary

Tags: probability, stationary-processes

This is from Wikipedia:
Let $Y$ have a uniform distribution $Y$ ~ $ U(0,2\pi]$ and define $ X_t = cos(t + Y )$ .

Then $ {X_t} $ is strictly stationary.

Could someone prove this for me ?

Cheers

Comment: If $a\in [-1,1]$ does $F_{X_t}(a)=P(X_t \leq a)$ depend on $t$?

Comment: It does, since the following isn't necessarily true:
$ P(cos(t_1+Y)<=a) = P(cos(t_2+Y)<=a) $

Comment: It doesn't dependent on $a$. In fact, for any $t$ we have $$P(X_t \leq a)=1-\frac{1}{\pi}\arccos(a)$$

Comment: I would take a look at this graph. The probability $P(X_t \leq a)$ equals the length of the black curve divided by $2\pi$. This will be the case for any $t$ since $t+Y \sim \mathcal{U}(t,t+ 2\pi]$ "sweeps through" a range of 
 $2\pi$ for any $t$. Here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w0jevohurs

Comment: Let me first adress that arcos isn't one to one since: $ cos(\pi/4)=cos(-\pi/4) $
But assuming you take an interval of angles for which arccos is one to one then you have the following:
You asked if the prob is dependent on t?
Well:
$ 
P(X_t <= a)=P(cos(t+Y)<=a)
=P(t+Y<= arccos(a))
=P(Y<=arccos(a)-t) = 1/2\pi * (arccos(a)-t)  
$

Comment: I didn't use any property of injectivity in my argument to establish the cdf. I used a purely  geometric argument. Also, the result you just wrote down is not correct. It's not even a valid cdf since, if it were, then taking would yield $a=1$ $$1=P(X_t\leq 1)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\big(\arccos(1)-t\big)=-\frac{t}{2\pi}$$ which is obviously not true.

Comment: Right, what I wrote is definitely not true. Where is the mistake though?
Also, let's consider another problem.
If $ Y ~ U(0,2\pi] $ and I define $ X_t = (t+Y)mod(2\pi) $.
Would $ X_t $ also be invariant of t?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119204/discussion-between-sammy-apsel-and-matthew-pilling).

Comment: Your mistake is where you claim that $$P\Big(\cos(t+Y)\leq a\Big) = P\Big(t+Y \leq \arccos(a)\Big) $$ You can't say $\arccos(\cos(A))=A$ when $A\notin[0,\pi]$. Also, $y=\arccos(x)$ is a decreasing function, so even if $t+Y$ belonged to $[0,\pi]$ you would have to change  $\leq$ to $\geq$. I suggest you draw a picture of the unit circle, draw the angle $\theta=t$ and the vertical line $x=a$, envision all angles from $\theta=t$ to $\theta=t+ 2\pi$, and ask yourself for which of these angles is the cosine less than or equal to $a$.